# Theorem (Continuous compact function in compact $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Above all, I want to say I am Sorry for posting many questions.

---

**Theorem 1.15 (Continuous compact function in compact $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$)**

Let $E$ be a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f$ be continuous in $E$ relative to $E$. Then,

1. $f$ is bounded on $E$; that is, $\sup_{\mathbf{x}\in E}|f(\mathbf{x})| \lt \infty$
2. $f$ attains its supremum and infimum on $E$; i.e., there exist $\mathbf{x_1}, \mathbf{x_2} \in E$ such that $f(\mathbf{x_1})=\sup_{\mathbf{x}\in E}f(\mathbf{x})$, $f(\mathbf{x_2})=\inf_{\mathbf{x}\in E}f(\mathbf{x})$
3. $f$ is uniformly continuous on $E$ relative to $E$; i.e., given $\varepsilon\gt0$, there exists $\delta\gt0$ such that $|f(\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{y})|\lt\varepsilon$ if $|f(\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{y})|\lt\delta$ and $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\in E$

---

**Example**

\begin{align}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x}~,&&x\gt0\\
0~, &&x=0\\
\sin\frac{1}{x}~, &&x\lt0
\end{cases}\end{align}

[image: graph]

---

If $E=\mathbb{R}$, then $E$ is not compact.

If $E=(0, 1]$, then $E$ is not compact.

If $E=[0, 1]$, then $E$ is compact but not continuous at $0$.

If $E=[1, 2]$, then $E$ is compact and continuous in $E$.

So, only the case in which $E$ is the interval $[1, 2]$, can satisfy three options specified above.

Is my concept right??

---

In addition, I want to ask why to say "in $E$ relative to $E$".

The sentence "$f$ is continuous in $E$ relative to $E$" is very weired to me.

What is the meaning of "in $E$ relative to $E$"